# Vim: Foldtext contain all content, instead of only the first line

Tags: regular-expression, folding, functions, join

Would like to have all content of the folded block, instead of only the first line.

My current foldsettings are:

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker={,}
```

Example how my data is structured:

```
{
  cows
  pigs
  chickens
}
```

Current folds look like:

```
+--  5 lines: ---------------------------
```

Ideally folds look like:

```
{  cows  pigs  chickens  } --------------
```

Have searched on the net for a while, unfortunately didn't succeed.

Comment: That's not what I'd call folding. In VIm folding _hides_ text/content. You're describing something different...compression or reformatting of text/content, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The option `foldtext` defines a expression, that is evaluated to create the text displayed for a closed fold. By default this is set to the build in function `foldtext()`.

You can create a custom function, to create the text displayed on a closed fold. The documentation `:help fold-foldtext` contains an example. Note that the resulting text is truncated to fit window width.

Answer (score 0):

An example of probably what you want:

[image]

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker={,}

set foldtext=MyFoldText()
fu! MyFoldText()
    let lineNr = v:foldstart
    let text = ""
    while (strlen(text) < winwidth(0) - v:foldlevel - 2) && lineNr <= v:foldend
        let text .= getline(lineNr).' '
        let lineNr += 1
    endwhile

    let text = v:folddashes . text
    if strlen(text) > winwidth(0) - 5 
        let text = strpart(text, 0, winwidth(0) - 5).' … }'
    endif
    return text
endfu
```

It is not 100% bulletproof, probably will make your vim slow. I could make it more generic (you see there are some figures I manually hardcoded) but I will leave it for you to tinker.